# Does water run through a kitchen faucet sprayer when the faucet is off?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet, sink

I was attempting to replace my faucet sprayer and hose today and discovered that the hose I bought was not compatible with the faucet.  I bought a hose that screws on, the one on the faucet has some sort of connector and a plastic latch and wire holding it together...

So, I have managed to reconnect the old hose and just let the broken sprayer sit for the time being.  I'm concerned with how securely I have the sprayer hose on at the moment. My question is - If the water faucet is off and the valves on and the sprayer hose manages to become detached from the underside of the faucet, will there be a torrential outpouring of water, or is the water technically not running through the hose until the faucet itself is turned on?

Answer (score 6):

There is no water pressure to the sprayer unless the faucet itself is turned on.  You can verify this by simply depressing the handle on the sprayer while the faucet it off.

Comment: So as long as it doesn't leak while the faucet is on, I am in no fear of leaving my house and having this hose magically come off, and any substantial amount of water flooding my house.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

If the faucet is turned off, no water is going to come out of the sprayer or the spout.

If you are concerned then just test it out - turn the faucet off and disconnect the hose.

Comment: So as long as it doesn't leak while the faucet is on, I am in no fear of leaving my house and having this hose magically come off, and any substantial amount of water flooding my house.

Comment: As long as it doesn't leak while it is off then you are safe - its not going to magically turn on.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the faucet valves control the flow and mix function. However the hose will be pressureized any time the faucet is used. This means if you use the faucet there is a chance the hose can come off and cause a small flood.